# Is it safe to block with ppoll on one thread, and read/write to the same fds on another?

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, c++11

I'm designing a program (C++11, targeting Linux, CentOS 7 if it matters) where one thread will call ppoll to block on multiple fds, while any reading/writing for these fds will take place on other threads. All these fds will be set to non-blocking.

Naturally, my question is, do I need to ensure that any particular fd is not being polled on while it is being used for reading/writing, or is it safe to not put in any concurrency checks for this?

The man page for [select](http://linux.die.net/man/2/select) mentions multi-threading issues with closing an fd while polling on it but says nothing about reading/writing, and poll and other related functions just refer back to select. So I would assume there is no problem, but I am looking for a definitive source like a standard that says yes it is safe or no it is not.

Comment: The official reference for [`pselect`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pselect.html) and [`poll`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/poll.html) doesn't mention anything about the issue. The `ppoll` function is a Linux extension and not standardized, so the "definitive source" would in this case be the actual Linux source code.

Answer (score 1):

The select and poll methods are not thread-safe. If you want a thread-safe alternative, you should look at `epoll`. Besides MT, it is faster for big sets of file descriptors. The epoll approach leaves the kernel responsible for managing the fd set, which garantees you can wait on the same set with multiple threads.

If you receive, let's say, a POLLOUT event in a thread and queue the event for another thread to treat it, poll/select will keep returning imediately until the treating thread finishes dealing with the POLLOUT event.

Polling for multiple events using kernel methods heavily depends on platform. Even though UNIX-like systems have similar approaches, they are not portable at all.

Comment: POSIX doesn't list either `select` or `poll` in the list of functions not guaranteed to be thread-safe. The Linux documentation specifically states that both `select` and `poll` are thread-safe.

Answer (score 0):

I have used poll() on multiple fds in one thread while another thread reads or writes on those fds...You will get the events POLLIN when the other thread writes to it....When one of the fds gets closed, you will get a POLLNVAL.So, your thread unblocks and you can check which fd caused it, remove it from the set of fds you are polling and continue polling with the new File Descriptor set.

```
struct pollfd *fds
struct pollfd {
    int   fd;         /* file descriptor */
    short events;     /* requested events */
    short revents;    /* returned events */
};
```

You can check the data through the above structure.

On the other hand if you want to unblock the polling thread before closing a particular file descriptor and you do not want to poll for it, you can use a pipe[].
Pipe will give you two fd's read and write fd.
You can add the read end of the pipe to the fdset of the polling thread and use the write end from other thread as a signalling mechanism to unblock the polling thread and manipulate the pollfdset, whenever you need to manipulate it.